# android c2dm SenderId mismatch error?

Tags: android

I am working with a messaging application using c2dm.. I get registered my app with c2dm..But the time am sending message to any particular id who is using my app, getting errors saying that "Sender Id mismatch".. What it will be ? can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set the sender_id in the client code with the email 
address you registered to the c2dm servers (the one you use in the 
http post to send messages).

usedintent.putExtra("sender","yourMail@gmail.com");

Comment: if mail id is wrong or null how individual user gets registration id back through my code ?

Comment: this id must be activated. you have waited some days for activation to be confirmed?

Comment: bro am getting registration id for each user through my app, but when i want to send a message to a particular id it shows the above said error..